# Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.add' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, gradle

Once I implemented "polyline" with google maps i got this error.
thanks to anyone who can help me

```
../../../flutter_linux_2.0.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:55:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.add' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'.
  void add(String name, value) {                                        
       ^                                                                
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:699:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('add').
  void add(String name, Object value,                                   
       ^                                                                
../../../flutter_linux_2.0.2-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:70:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.set' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.set'.
  void set(String name, Object value) {                                 
       ^                                                                
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:708:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('set').
  void set(String name, Object value,                                   
       ^                                                                
                                                                        
                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* Where:                                                                
Script '/home/rafael/Scrivania/flutter_linux_2.0.2-stable/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.              
> Process 'command '/home/rafael/Scrivania/flutter_linux_2.0.2-stable/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: According to this [github thread](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/780), updating the Dio version to 3.0.9 solves the issue. Have you already tried this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue is that the `HttpHeaders.add` method that `DioHttpHeaders.add` overrides seems to have been changed, requiring arguments that's not previously requested. [Updating the plugin version](https://github.com/cfug/dio/issues/780#issuecomment-627739499) should solve the issue.